# Setting prototype in object literal

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I am a beginner learning JavaScript. Reading through this page, I can't understand how this piece of code is defining an object. I expect the " foo: bar" construct and not sure if `__proto__` is a builtin name or doing something special here. What is going on?

> In ES2015, object literals are extended to support setting the prototype at construction, shorthand for foo: foo assignments, defining methods, making super calls, and computing property names with expressions. Together, these also bring object literals and class declarations closer together, and let object-based design benefit from some of the same conveniences. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals)
>
> ```
> var obj = {
>     // __proto__
>     __proto__: theProtoObj,
>     // Shorthand for ‘handler: handler’
>     handler,
>     // Methods
>     toString() {
>      // Super calls
>      return "d " + super.toString();
>     },
>     // Computed (dynamic) property names
>     [ 'prop_' + (() => 42)() ]: 42
> };
> ```

Comment: Pretty much everything there is to know about `__proto__` can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code snippet is really a bunch of [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for plain old `key: value` notation.

### `__proto__: theProtoObj,`

Yes, this is a special field, not just an arbitrary name. It is the object used when searching up the inheritance tree. Its' explicit use is generally discouraged. Read [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-__proto__-and-prototype) for a better understanding of it.

### `handler,`

This is syntactic sugar for `handler: handler`. Frequently do you want to have a field in an object and assign it a value from a variable with the same name, so they included that shorthand in the specification.

```
var x = 10;
var y = 15;

// longhand
var point = { x: x, y: y };

// shorthand
var point = { x, y };
```

### `toString() {`

This is syntactic sugar for:

```
var obj = {
    toString: function () {
        ...
    }
};
```

### `return "d " + super.toString();`

The `super` keyword makes calling functions from a parent class much more clear. Where before it would look something like this:

```
var Person = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var Engineer = function (name) {
    // "super call"
    Person.call(this, name);

    this.profession = 'Engineer';
}
```

Now it can look like this:

```
class Engineer extends Person {
    constructor (name) {
        super(name);

        this.profession = 'Engineer';
    }
}
```

### `[ 'prop_' + (() => 42)() ]: 42`

Probably my favorite. This syntax allows you to have *dynamic* key names in the object literal. Before, you would have to do this:

```
var obj = {};
obj['prop_' + 42] = 42;
```

But, with the dynamic literal syntax, you can do this:

```
var obj = {
    ['prop_' + 42]: 42
};
```

### `(() => 42)()`

Syntactic sugar for:

```
// create an anonymous function and call it immediately
(function () {
    return 42;
})();
```